# error: strcpy was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, deprecated

I get this problem in a c++ problem compiling in Ubuntu g++ version 4.4.3.
I dont know the headers to include to solve this problem.. Thanks

```
centro_medico.cpp: In constructor ‘Centro_medico::Centro_medico(char*, char*, int, int, float)’:
centro_medico.cpp:5: error: ‘strcpy’ was not declared in this scope
centro_medico.cpp:13: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
centro_medico.cpp:13: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
centro_medico.cpp: In member function ‘Centro_medico& Centro_medico::operator=(const Centro_medico&)’:
centro_medico.cpp:26: error: ‘strcpy’ was not declared in this scope
centro_medico.cpp:39: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
centro_medico.cpp:39: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
centro_medico.cpp: In member function ‘bool Centro_medico::quitar_medico(int)’:
centro_medico.cpp:92: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
centro_medico.cpp:92: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
centro_medico.cpp: In member function ‘void Centro_medico::mostrar_especialidades(std::ostream&) const’:
centro_medico.cpp:123: error: ‘strcmpi’ was not declared in this scope
centro_medico.cpp: In member function ‘void Centro_medico::mostrar_horarios_consulta(char*) const’:
centro_medico.cpp:162: error: ‘strcmpi’ was not declared in this scope
centro_medico.cpp: In member function ‘void Centro_medico::crea_medicos()’:
centro_medico.cpp:321: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
centro_medico.cpp:321: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
```

---

medico.cpp

```
#include "medico.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib>  
#include<cstring>
#include<string>

long Medico::total_consultas=0; 
Medico::Medico(char *nom,char * espe,int colegiado,int trabajo)
{
int i;
strcpy(nombre,nom);
strcpy(especialidad,espe);
num_colegiado=colegiado;
num_horas_diarias=trabajo;
citas_medico= new Cita*[5]; // 5 Días de las semana, de Lunes a Viernes.
for (i=0;i<5;i++)
citas_medico[i]=new Cita[num_horas_diarias];
}



Medico::Medico(const Medico &m){
  int i;
  citas_medico=new Cita*[5];
  for (i=0;i<5;i++)
   citas_medico[i]=NULL;
 (*this) = m;
}

Medico &Medico::operator=(const Medico &m){
 int i,j;
 if (this != &m) { // Para evitar la asignación de un objeto a sí mismo
     strcpy(nombre,m.nombre);
     strcpy(especialidad,m.especialidad);     
     num_colegiado=m.num_colegiado;
     num_horas_diarias=m.num_horas_diarias;
     for (i=0;i<5;i++){
      delete citas_medico[i]; 
      citas_medico[i]=new Cita[num_horas_diarias];
      for(j=0;j<num_horas_diarias;j++){
       citas_medico[i][j] = m.citas_medico[i][j] ;
       }
     }     
  }
 return *this;
}
```

---

medico.h

```
#pragma once
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "cita.h"

class Medico
{
 private:
                char nombre[50];
                char especialidad[50];
                int num_colegiado;
                int num_horas_diarias;
                Cita **citas_medico;
                static long total_consultas;                
 public:
                void mostrar_calendario_citas(ostream &o=cout) const;
                bool asignar_cita(int d, int hor,Paciente *p=NULL);
                void anular_cita(int d, int hor);
                bool consultar_cita(char dni[10], int modificar=0);
                void modificar_cita(int d, int hor);                
                void vaciar_calendario_citas();
                void borrar_calendario_citas();                
                char* get_especialidad(char espec[50]) const;
                char* get_nombre(char n[50]) const;
                int get_num_colegiado() const;
                int get_num_horas() const;
                void set_num_horas(int horas);
                void mostrar_info(ostream &o=cout) const;
                static long get_total_consultas();
                Cita* operator[](int dia);
                void eliminar_calendario_citas();
                void crear_calendario_citas();    
                Medico(char *nom,char * espe,int colegiado,int trabajo);
                Medico(const Medico &m);
                Medico &operator=(const Medico &c);
                void operator delete(void*);
                ~Medico();
 };
 ostream& operator<<(ostream &o, Medico &c);
 ofstream& operator<<(ofstream &fichero, Medico &m);
 ifstream& operator>>(ifstream &fichero, Medico &m);
```

Comment: what's up with the `#include` abuse?

Comment: please reformat your code, removing all the unnecessary vertical whitespace

Comment: Why not use std::string instead of char*? Also strcpy is a potential security risk for it does not check array boundaries.

Comment: Yes the problem is because im compiling with the windows gcc compiler, and when i change to Ubuntu, and try to compile i get this error, thanks

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Observations:

- `#include <cstring>` should introduce std::strcpy().
- `using namespace std;` (as written in medico.h) introduces any identifiers from `std::` into the global namespace.

Aside from `using namespace std;` being somewhat clumsy once the application grows larger (as it introduces one hell of a lot of identifiers into the global namespace), and that you should **never** use `using` in a header file (see below!), `using namespace` does not affect identifiers introduced *after* the statement.

(`using namespace std` is written in the header, which is included in medico.cpp, but `#include <cstring>` comes *after* that.)

**My advice:** Put the `using namespace std;` (if you insist on using it at all) into medico.cpp, *after any includes*, and use explicit `std::` in medico.h.

---

`strcmpi()` is not a standard function at all; while being defined on Windows, you have to solve case-insensitive compares differently on Linux.

(On general terms, I would like to point to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313970/how-to-convert-stdstring-to-lower-case/24063783#24063783) with regards to "proper" string handling in C and C++ that takes Unicode into account, as every application should. Summary: The standard *cannot* handle these things correctly; *do* use [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/).)

---

```
warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
```

A "string constant" is when you write a string literal (e.g. `"Hello"`) in your code. Its type is `const char[]`, i.e. array of *constant* characters (as you cannot change the characters). You can assign an array to a pointer, but assigning to `char *`, i.e. removing the `const` qualifier, generates the warning you are seeing.

---

OT clarification: `using` in a header file changes visibility of identifiers for anyone including that header, which is usually not what the user of your header file wants. For example, I could use `std::string` and a self-written `::string` just perfectly in my code, *unless I include your medico.h*, because then the two classes will clash.

Don't use `using` in header files.

And even in implementation files, it can introduce lots of ambiguity. There is a case to be made to use explicit namespacing in implementation files as well.

Comment: Thank u, i think o solve the problem of error: ‘strcmpi’ was not declared in this scope

I get another warning: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the other two warning types. I usually fix only the first error before recompiling, as quite often many of the subsequent errors / warnings are follow-ups that vanish once the topmost problem is solved. I extended my answer to cover the other two cases.

Comment: " am not at all sure if using namespace affects identifiers introduced after the statement." - it *only* affects identifiers introduced after the statement. It means that if an unqualified identifier is used later, then the `namespace std` will be searched for that identifier.  (It sounds as if you're treating it as "import `std` into global" or something, which is not how it works).

Answer (score 3):

When you say:

```
 #include <cstring>
```

the g++ compiler should put the `<string.h>` declarations it itself includes into the `std::` AND the global namespaces. It looks for some reason as if it is not doing that. Try replacing one instance of `strcpy` with `std::strcpy` and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Not correct. `<cstring>` *does* put the declarations into `std::`, but whether or not it also puts them in the global namespace depends on the implementation. I am not sure if the standard even allows putting them into global, but I am positive it does not *require* it.

Comment: It does allow it, currently doesn't require it, and the behaviour I was talking about was that of g++. On my installation (version 4.4.1) it does what I said.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit anal-retentive when it comes to the language standards. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This error sometimes occurs in a situation like this:

```
#ifndef NAN
#include <stdlib.h>
#define NAN (strtod("NAN",NULL))
#endif

static void init_random(uint32_t initseed=0)
{
    if (initseed==0)
    {
        struct timeval tv;
        gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
        seed=(uint32_t) (4223517*getpid()*tv.tv_sec*tv.tv_usec);
    }
    else
        seed=initseed;
#if !defined(CYGWIN) && !defined(__INTERIX)
    //seed=42
    //SG_SPRINT("initializing random number generator with %d (seed size %d)\n", seed, RNG_SEED_SIZE)
    initstate(seed, CMath::rand_state, RNG_SEED_SIZE);
#endif
}
```

If the following code lines not run in the run-time:

```
#ifndef NAN
#include <stdlib.h>
#define NAN (strtod("NAN",NULL))
#endif
```

you will face with an error in your code like something as follows; because *initstate* is placed in the ***stdlib.h*** file and *it's not included*:

```
In file included from ../../shogun/features/SubsetStack.h:14:0, 
                 from ../../shogun/features/Features.h:21, 
                 from ../../shogun/ui/SGInterface.h:7, 
                 from MatlabInterface.h:15, 
                 from matlabInterface.cpp:7: 
../../shogun/mathematics/Math.h: In static member function 'static void shogun::CMath::init_random(uint32_t)': 
../../shogun/mathematics/Math.h:459:52: error: 'initstate' was not declared in this scope
```