# C++ function template question

Tags: c++, templates

I was searching on the best way to lcase/ucase a C++ STL class and I came across this post:

[STL string to lower case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313970/stl-string-to-lower-case)

One of the solutions given was:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string> 

std::string data = “Abc”; 
std::transform(data.begin(), data.end(), data.begin(), ::tolower);
```

However, transform is defined in stl_algo.h as:

```
  template<typename _InputIterator, typename _OutputIterator,
       typename _UnaryOperation>
    _OutputIterator
    transform(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last,
          _OutputIterator __result, _UnaryOperation __unary_op)
    {
...
```

So how come it is being called without providing the template instantiation parameters?

To clarify my question, I was expecting the transform function to be called like:

```
transform(std::string::iterator, std::string::iterator, 
          /* not sure what to put here for the predicate */);
```

Is this a one off (a special case), or am I missing something fundamental?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called [Template Argument Deduction](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.vacpp7l.doc/language/ref/clrc16tmpl_arg_deduction.htm).

[Here](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/409) is another nice article explaining Template Argument Deduction.

Answer (score 1):

Template parameters are implicitly derived from the function arguments.