# Disable unwanted overload for tolower

Tags: c++, c++11

While researching, I found [**Why “transform(s.begin(),s.end(),s.begin(),tolower)” can't be complied successfully?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5539249/4320030) , and the solution is to use `::tolower`. As an exercise, I want to see if I can disable that (in *locale* header file) overload and use `std::tolower`. First, we start simple:

```
template <typename charT> charT tolower(charT c, std::locale const& loc) = delete;

int main()
{
    std::vector<char> chars = { 'a', 'D', 'c', 'b' };
    std::transform(chars.begin(), chars.end(), chars.begin(), std::tolower);
}
```

The compiler cannot **deduce** the correct overload. So we provide the char template:

```
std::transform(chars.begin(), chars.end(), chars.begin(), std::tolower<char>);
```

So we're back to square one. I know it is **undefined behavior**, but I thought I could put it into namespace std:

```
namespace std {
template <typename charT> charT tolower(charT c, std::locale const& loc) = delete;
}
```

Now the compiler says I'm redefining the function.

```
using std::tolower;
template <typename charT> charT tolower(charT c, std::locale const& loc) = delete;
```

doesn't work either.

Now this is pointless exercise, but is this possible?

Comment: Explicitly deleting a function doesn't remove it from overload resolution; it just means you get an error if that overload is chosen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't disable the other overload, but there are lots of ways to ensure the correct one is chosen:

```
int (*lower)(int) = std::tolower;
std::transform(chars.begin(), chars.end(), chars.begin(), lower);
```

or

```
std::transform(chars.begin(), chars.end(), chars.begin(), static_cast<int(*)(int)>(std::tolower));
```

or

```
std::transform(chars.begin(), chars.end(), chars.begin(), [](int c) { return std::tolower(c); });
```

or

```
struct ToLower {
  int operator()(int c) const { return std::tolower(c); }
};
std::transform(chars.begin(), chars.end(), chars.begin(), ToLower{});
```

The first two forms tell the compiler how to choose the right overload from the overload set, because only one of the overloads can be converted to a function pointer of that type.

The second two forms create a wrapper that invokes `tolower` so that normal overload resolution finds the right one, and you don't need to take the address of `tolower`.