# Does C++ have a free function `size(object)`?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, c++17, non-member-functions

It seems that the way that most people find the size of a `string` is they just use the `my_string.size()` and it works fine. Well, I recently did an assignment for class where I did...

```
if (size(my_string) < 5)
    store[counter].setWeight(stoi(my_string));
```

Instead of....

```
if (my_string.size() < 5)
    store[counter].setWeight(stoi(my_string));
```

But to my suprise my instructor, who I believe is running an older compiler, wasn't able to run that line of code. On my compiler it works both ways and I'm not quite sure why.

A complete program (it outputs 4 for both):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string myvar = "1000";
    cout << "Using size(myvar) = " << size(myvar) << endl;
    cout << "Using myvar.size() = " << myvar.size() << endl;
}
```

If anyone can shed some light on why my solution to the problem worked on my Machine but not my Professors? Also, I'm currently running VS2015.

Comment: What is the type of `temp`? What is the function `sizeof` do?

Comment: interchangeable size(x) and x.size() are proposed for c++17

Comment: Temp is of type string and temp.size() and size(temp) are both designed to get how many characters are in temp; to my surprise they both will return the same value, and size isn't defined anywhere else in my program because I thought of that as well.

Comment: Show us the **complete** program. The code you’ve shown isn’t complete and won’t compile.

Comment: @WillBriggs more than likely an outdated one; Richard Hodges could VS 2015 have already implemented these changes to get people used to them in c++ 17? Konrad Rudolph the sample program just containing the main method at the bottom will run on my machine, will it not run on yours?

Comment: @Feek: It's possible. [This is not valid C++14](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6aa3ebe14ebf0500), I can tell you that much.

Comment: Out of interest, _why_ did you do it this way? Who told/taught you to?

Comment: In the Visual Studio 2015 release notes it states that "size(), empty(), and data() non-member functions are now provided. C++17". Does this imply that they have implemented what @Richard Hodges stated?

Comment: It outright proves that they have implemented what @Richard Hodges stated.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Nobody really taught me anything about c++; All of my school taught programming languages have been Java and I just transferred to a school that is exclusively c++. So I'm having to self teach myself a lot.

Comment: Right, but you must have seen non-member `size` used somewhere .. or was it just an accident that it slipped into your code?

Comment: @RichardHodges Dunno about that, I was awfully happy with their `regex` implementation while gcc was dragging it's feet. Then again I was furious that it took them forever to implement `initializer_list`s.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

MSVS 2015 has a `size` function defined in xutility

```
template<class _Container>
auto inline size(const _Container& _Cont)
    -> decltype(_Cont.size())
{   // get size() for container
return (_Cont.size());
}
```

This is the function that is being used when you call

```
cout << "Using size(myvar) = " << size(myvar) << endl;
```

This is not a standard C++11/14 function and will not run on [gcc](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/21207e47e86ec5ed) or [clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9028163890b1d196)

This was detailed in the blog post [C++11/14/17 Features In VS 2015 RTM](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/06/19/c-11-14-17-features-in-vs-2015-rtm.aspx)

Comment: Agreed. Since it's not found in MSVS 2013, this is most likely an early implementation of a C++17 feature. (I wish they'd stop doing that -.-) [edit: confirmed by release notes - worth adding to the answer?]

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Agreed.  They should make it an option

Comment: As an aside, even abstaining from `using namespace std;` ([Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)) wouldn't have changed anything due to [ADL](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl), as `std::string` is also in `std`.

Answer (score 13):

[`size`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) is actually C++17 functionality. The real benefit to is akin to the benefit of [`begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [`end`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) from C++11.

Note that the first definition of `size` simply returns the container's size method.

So if I have a templated function like this:

```
template <typename T>
auto foo(const T& bar) { return bar.size(); }
```

This could only be used with containers, but if I change that to:

```
template <typename T>
auto foo(const T& bar) { return size(bar); }
```

It can be used with C-style arrays too. I've added a live example here: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Rlpi5wueA14JOW2P

*In summary, you should always use `size` and other range based functions because of the improvements to generality and container agnostic code (see [here](https://topanswers.xyz/cplusplus?q=952#a1130) for more).*

Comment: @Deduplicator I'm aware that `void main()` is Microsoft only.  Since Microsoft has the only compiler that supports this right now I figured why not. If however it irritates you so much that you must edit the answer please add a `return 0;`. I'm going to roll back for now. If you feel convicted enough to try again, and add the `return` I won't roll it back.

Comment: @JonathanMee: In C++ and in C99+ `return 0;` at the end of `main` is implicit. Thus I didn't add it. Yes, [MS lists `void main()` as MS-specific](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wd819wh.aspx), but is there any reason to restrict your code to their compiler? Other standard-libraries wil soon enough add more C++1z features.

Comment: @Deduplicator Wha? `return 0` at the end of `main` is implicit? Can you give me a reference?

Comment: In C++ see \[basic.start.main\] ("*A return statement in main has the effect of leaving the main function (destroying any objects with automatic
storage duration) and calling std::exit with the return value as the argument. If control reaches the end
of main without encountering a return statement, the effect is that of executing
return 0;*").

Comment: In C99+ it's 5.1.2.2.3 Program termination ("*If the return type of the main function is a type compatible with int, a return from the
initial call to the main function is equivalent to calling the exit function with the value
returned by the main function as its argument;11) reaching the } that terminates the
main function returns a value of 0. If the return type is not compatible with int, the
termination status returned to the host environment is unspecified.*").

Comment: @Deduplicator I waited till I could verify that there were no warnings before rolling this back, but it appears that both gcc and Visual Studio handle the lack of a return silently. Makes you wonder what the point of `void main()` is at all... Anyway, this sure would make a great question and answer...

Answer (score 3):

According to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/06/19/c-11-14-17-features-in-vs-2015-rtm.aspx VS2015 started to support non-member `size` [n4280](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4280.pdf) proposal.

It's kinda weird they enable it out-of-the-box with out any define or compiler flag. But it seems like it. Currently it might be considered non-standard, although it is already voted in for c++17.

Comment: Just like `begin` and `end`, this is easy to implement!