# Why does checked_array_iterator work without including <iterator> in VS2013 but fails in VS2017?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2017

Given the following code:

```
#include <memory>
#include <locale>

int main() {
    auto source = std::make_unique<int[]>(16);
    auto dest = std::make_unique<int[]>(16);
    auto dp = stdext::checked_array_iterator<int*>(dest.get(), 16);
    std::copy_n(source.get(), 16, dp);
    return 0;
}
```

It compiles cleanly on Visual Studio 2013 by running `cl.exe /EHsc <file>.cpp`. However, on Visual Studio 2017 the following errors (among others) are thrown by `cl.exe`:

```
vc12.cpp(7): error C2653: 'stdext': is not a class or namespace name
vc12.cpp(7): error C2065: 'checked_array_iterator': undeclared identifier
```

Why does this code no longer compile?

Comment: The question might be very specific, but in a big project it took me quite a long time to figure out why it was compiling on VS2013 and no search engine yielded any results.

Comment: Btw, should be `int main`. `void main` is not portable C++.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: Yeah, I tried to keep it minimal. Will add the `int` and the `return`.

Comment: You don't need the return, flowing off the end of `main` implicitly returns some value indicating successful termination.

Answer (score 1):

The example is missing an `#include <iterator>`. Technically, it was also missing for Visual Studio 2013 (see [Why include what you use](https://github.com/include-what-you-use/include-what-you-use/blob/master/docs/WhyIWYU.md)), but due to the chain of includes it worked there. Between Visual Studio 2013 and Visual Studio 2017 the includes of the `std`-headers got revamped.

The example shows `#include <locale>`. In the old version, `#include <iterator>` was part of the include-chain of `locale`, which is no longer the case in Visual Studio 2017.

However, the documentation of VS2017 is hard to find at the moment since it is so new. The important document can be found at [doc.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/checked-array-iterator-class#requirements), it lists the required header `<iterator>`.

Answer (score 0):

This is included in [visual-studio-2017](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2017) according to the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/checked-array-iterator-class However you'll need to `#include <iterator>`.

Though rather than pursuing correcting this, I'd entourage writing standard conformant code. The best way to do that would be to just use a statically allocated array. This will allow you to use C++'s `begin`, `end`, and `size` functions to work with it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33442842/2642059

There are some cases where that wouldn't be a good suggestion, if a dynamic array is a must have, consider using a `vector`. If you can't abide a container then using a `unique_ptr` is a good way to do this, but rather than depending upon `checked_array_iterator` prefer maintaining your own size:

```
const size_t sourceSize = 16;
auto source = std::make_unique<int[]>(sourceSize);
auto dest = std::make_unique<int[]>(sourceSize);
std::copy_n(source.get(), sourceSize, dest.get())
```