# Is cout Guaranteed to Have the ctype<char> facet?

Tags: c++, locale, cout, facet, ctype

Given: `auto foo = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"s` I can convert all the characters to lowercase by:

```
use_facet<ctype<char>>(cout.getloc()).tolower(data(foo), next(data(foo), foo.size()));
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/rWzza8)

But this depends upon `cout.getloc()` containing the `ctype<char>` `facet`.

Presuming that I'm using an unmodified `cout` can I assume that `cout.getloc()` will contain the `facet` `ctype<char>` or do I need to confirm this before use with:

```
has_facet<ctype<char>>(cout.getloc())
```

Comment: FYI I closed that question as a dupe.  You may want to move your answer to the target instead of having it on the linked to question.

Comment: @NathanOliver Man the Roomba got to that fast. I gotta hurry up and get to 10k so I can see my answers on deleted questions! Anyway, I've typed something up from memory on the correct question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37438120/2642059 Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: [Here](http://pastebin.com/kkvYp7fj)(pastebin-link) is the source of your answer

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks, I appreciate you grabbing that for me! I've used it to update the answer, eliminating the link to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37435426/2642059

Comment: hm guys the question linked gives a 404, "removed from stackoverflow by reasons of moderation"

Comment: @coyotte508 Sounds like we both need to get to 10K so we can see that answer! I've updated the question with the relevant sections from my answer there.

Comment: @NathanOliver HAHA! Finally made it to 10K! I can see the question again! Who knows what mayhem I can wreck with this new-found power!

Comment: @JonathanMee Congrats, Now you can be power drunk like the rest of us ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale):

> Each locale constructed in a C++ program holds at least the following standard facets [...]:
>
> 1. std::ctype<char>
> 2. ...

*Any* locale, meaning even locales not of the `cout` object will support `std::ctype<char>`.