# Which tolower in C++?

Tags: c++, string, locale, ctype, tolower

Given `string foo`, I've written [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37438120/2642059) on how to use `cctype`'s [`tolower`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower) to convert the characters to lowercase

```
transform(cbegin(foo), cend(foo), begin(foo), static_cast<int (*)(int)>(tolower))
```

But I've [begun to consider](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37436755/2642059) `locale`'s [`tolower`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/tolower), which could be used like this:

```
use_facet<ctype<char>>(cout.getloc()).tolower(data(foo), next(data(foo), foo.size()));
```

- Is there a reason to prefer one of these over the other?
- Does their functionality differ at all?
- I mean other than the fact that `tolower` accepts and returns an `int` which I assume is just some antiquated C stuff?

Comment: man, only c++ can make such easy things so difficult...

Comment: why the `static_cast` ? Just do `std::transform(foo.cbegin(), foo.cend(), foo.begin(), ::tolower)`. Alternatively, consider [boost's `to_lower`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost/algorithm/to_lower.html).

Comment: @SanderDeDycker: yes, but he is asking the why! only one reason comes to my mind right now, which i posted as answer... but i guess there are more, maybe also considering performance.

Comment: @progressive_overload With Great Power Comes Great Responsibility

Comment: @exilit converting a string to lowercase using a 86-liner is the most powerful thing i've ever seen in my life

Comment: @progressive_overload : I made a comment, not an answer. I didn't claim to answer the OP's question. I pointed out an oddity, and suggested an alternative that I consider to be better than either of the suggested ones.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker I see, but I would like to know the why as well. :) it is shorter... that is an advantage for sure, but is there more to it?

Comment: @SanderDeDycker You than check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37438120/2642059 `::tolower` is implementation dependent, and I *always* try to avoid Boost.

Comment: @progressive_overload : boost's `to_lower` is shorter, more readable, and has the option to pass in a locale as well.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker Boost always has the massive drawback that you must include the Boost libraries. I recognize there is a place for Boost's convenience, but using it when C++ already provides you not 1 but 2 ways to accomplish this... well it doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @progressive_overload I don't want to start a flame-war, just saying that: Sure this is specific task could be solved easier, but on the other hand the STL provides you great flexibility (power). And sometimes what's an advantage in one case is a drawback in another.

Comment: @Alex Good catch I've looked at this question like 10 times today and missed it every time. You must program without Intelisense to have the eagle-eye to catch that ;)

Comment: @JonathanMee : `::tolower` works fine with `#include <ctype.h>` - it's all about choices (I'd personally rather put these few functions in the global namespace than to have to deal with overload disambiguation). And about boost : many people want to avoid it as much as possible - I learned to embrace it, but to each their own. I prefer the readability advantage it provides, as well as the seamless support for non-ASCII encodings and locales.

Comment: @JonathanMee : oh, and boost does not always require you to include boost libraries. Much of the boost functionality is headers only. Including the functionality I suggested.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker The standard has deprecated `ctype.h`, hence the use of `cctype` which necessitates the `static_cast`. Anyway even though I don't want to include Boost, I recognize and share your readability concerns. The standard could do a lot better here.

Comment: @JonathanMee : everyone makes their own choices. Unfortunately, my set of choices is incompatible with yours for this specific subject, so my suggestions weren't useful to you. I apologize. Hopefully they can be useful to someone else in the future :)

Comment: Regardless of everything you have to cast to `uint8_t` or `unsigned char` before converting to `int` because otherwise you may get unwanted sign extension depending on your platform!

Comment: @sehe Can you elaborate, `string` works with `signed char`s; why would I  want to cast to `unsigned char` when using `tolower`?

Comment: @SanderDeDycker Please don't apologize. I sometimes work in solutions where Boost is already included if I need to do this in such a solution I'll go look up Boost's `tolower`. So you have provided me with some helpful guidance. It's just not the answer that I want for this question.

Comment: @JonathanMee std::string uses `char` which may or may not be signed.

Comment: @JonathanMee thank post-review for nor not doing syntax highlighting.

Comment: @sehe Isn't `string` defined as `basic_string<char>`? So it will be signed?

Comment: I already dissected everything you need to see what's wrong.

Comment: @JonathanMee `char` may or may not be signed, that is implementation defined.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Hmmm, I'm not sure about that, "signed is default if omitted": http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Modifiers

Comment: @JonathanMee On the same page, see this passage: "`char` - type for character representation which can be most efficiently processed on the target system (has the same representation and alignment as either signed char or unsigned char, but is always a distinct type)."

Comment: @JonathanMee I am sure I'm right. You want me to find the standard quote or do you believe me? :)

Comment: @BaummitAugen If I have to change everything I've believed about the `signed` modifier could you at least grace me with a citation from the standard?

Comment: @JonathanMee Sure thing. ;) *"It is implementation-defined whether objects of `char` type are represented as signed or
unsigned quantities. The `signed` specifier forces `char` objects to be signed; it is redundant in other contexts."* 7.1.6.2 [decl.type.simple] in N4140.

Comment: The C classification functions require the input value to be representable by `unsigned char` or be equal to `EOF`. Thus calling them directly with plain `char` is invalid if it is signed and the value is negative.

Comment: @T.C. So if I understand what you're saying correctly, if I am working with a `signed char[]` using `cctype`'s `tolower` is invalid o.O

Comment: @JonathanMee Due to my quote above, that might even be true for plain `char[]`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21805674/do-i-need-to-cast-to-unsigned-char-before-calling-toupper).

Comment: @BaummitAugen So because `locale`'s `tolower` works with `char`s not `int`s, it should be preferred then? That may be as good an argument as any as far as why I should choose one over the other. Are you interested in writing it up, if not I can.

Comment: @JonathanMee I always just used the C one with the cast, non-trivial string handling was never in the scope of my work. Feel free to write it up and use the potential UB (which is an atrocity, I agree) as argument.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Welp, I've done it. I've written up an answer citing basically the determining factor being whether you are willing to work with the cast. I expect to accept this tomorrow unless you have any showstopping comments or an answer of your own you'd like to add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be noted that the language designers *were* aware of `cctype`'s `tolower` when `locale`'s `tolower` was created. It improved in 2 primary ways:

1. As is mentioned in [progressive_overload's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37482763/2642059) the `locale` version allowed the use of the `facet ctype`, even a user modified one, *without* requiring the shuffling in of a new `LC_CTYPE` in via `setlocale` and the restoration of the previous `LC_CTYPE`
2. From section 7.1.6.2[dcl.type.simple]3:

> It is implementation-defined whether objects of `char` type are represented as signed or unsigned quantities. The `signed` specifier forces `char` objects to be signed

Which creates an the potential for undefined behavior with the `cctype` version of [`tolower`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower)'s if it's argument:

> Is not representable as `unsigned char` and does not equal `EOF`

So there is an additional input and output `static_cast` required by the `cctype` version of `tolower` yielding:

```
transform(cbegin(foo), cend(foo), begin(foo), [](const unsigned char i){ return tolower(i); });
```

Since the `locale` version operates directly on `char`s there is no need for a type conversion.

**So if you don't need to perform the conversion in a different `facet ctype` it simply becomes a style question of whether you prefer the `transform` with a lambda required by the `cctype` version, or whether you prefer the `locale` version's:**

```
use_facet<ctype<char>>(cout.getloc()).tolower(data(foo), next(data(foo), size(foo)));
```

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately,both are equally bad. Although `std::string`  pretends to be a utf-8 encoded string, non of the methods/function (including tolower), are really utf-8 aware. So, `tolower` / `tolower` + locale may work with characters which are single byte (= ASCII), they will fail for every other set of languages.

On Linux, I'd use ICU library. On Windows, I'd use `CharUpper` function.

Comment: You're saying that `locale`'s `tolower` can't handle UTF-8 either? Hmmm, that would have been a good argument for it.

Comment: @JonathanMee Unfortunately, C++ has no meaningful Unicode support in any sense.

Comment: C++ sucks at this indeed, but are you meaning that in 2016 we can't even have a portable library to handle this ?

Comment: @BaummitAugen Are you guys sure about the lack of UTF-8 support? That's actually one of the things demonstrated in the http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/tolower example. I haven't been able to come up with a way to make it fail with UTF-8, even when using "multi-byte characters".

Comment: @JonathanMee [Rekt](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/sqfCxno1uuqTMINX), output should be `ω`.

Comment: @JonathanMee And then there is stuff like [this](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/BGpUj2aBJi0APCRh) which should yield `SS`, but have fun building that with the normal `char` types.

Comment: @BaummitAugen You are right :( The input I tested with was just `wchar_t` on Windows not UTF-8. UTF-8 is still broken. Return to your lives citizens. In other news, I happen to have done some personal research on the 'ß' character though. According to the standard it should *not* convert to "SS" nor to 'ẞ': http://stackoverflow.com/a/37571371/2642059

Comment: @JonathanMee Unicode says it should: *"German 
sharp s
. 
The German 
sharp s
 character has several complications in case mapping.
Not  only  does  its  uppercase  mapping  expand  in  length,  but  its  default  case-pairings  are
asymmetrical. The default case mapping operations follow standard German orthography,
which uses the string “SS” as the regular uppercase mapping for U+00DF ß 
latin small
letter sharp s
."* Unicode 8 5.18 And Unicode is the standard that defines the behavior of UTF8, not some C++ standard.

Answer (score 4):

In the first case (cctype) the locale is set implicitely:

> Converts the given character to lowercase according to the character
>   conversion rules defined by the currently installed C locale.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower

In the second (locale's) case you have to explicitely set the locale:

> Converts parameter c to its lowercase equivalent if c is an uppercase
>   letter and has a lowercase equivalent, as determined by the ctype
>   facet of locale loc. If no such conversion is possible, the value
>   returned is c unchanged.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/tolower/