# Cant get string::size_type + int to do toupper

Tags: c++, string, find, uppercase, size-type

I want to use `toupper` on each `char` after point `.` in the `string`. 
I tried this code but I an getting a black screen when I start the program if I use `+` operator.

```
string fulltext = "my name is John. i have a girlfriend. her name is Anna";

string::size_type idx = 0;
while ((idx = fulltext.find(".")) != string::npos)
{
    if (idx != string::npos)
    {

        fulltext[idx + 2] = toupper(fulltext[idx + 2]);
    }
}
cout << fulltext << endl;
```

Comment: Define "It's not working". In addition to that, did you try using the debugger?

Comment: Probably because no incrementation of idx occurs, so you are going to get an infinite loop where you are setting the character "i" in ". i have" to upper. You might want to use idx = fulltext.find( ".", idx + 1 )

Comment: Also, some other issues in your code: 1) your `if` clause is not needed, since the same condition is checked in the `while`, and if you are in the loop, it is already `true`. 2) If `idx` represents a valid index in your string, it doesn't, automatically, mean, that `idx + 2` would represent a valid index.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that the only standard defined way to use `toupper` is to pass an `unsigned char`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37593205/2642059 Thus, the best way to do this is with a lambda in a [`transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform), for example you could capitalize `string fulltext` in it's entirety like this:

```
transform(cbegin(fulltext), cend(fulltext), begin(fulltext), [](const unsigned char idx){ return toupper(idx); })
```

Since you want to start at the first `'.'` and `transform` works on `iterator`s you could just use `find` to obtain an `iterator` to the `'.'` and use it in the 1<sup>st</sup> and 3<sup>rd</sup> arguments of `transform`: `auto it = find(begin(fulltext), end(fulltext), '.')` But we can avoid the temporary if we do reverse iteration:

```
transform(crbegin(fulltext), make_reverse_iterator(find(cbegin(fulltext), cend(fulltext), '.')), rbegin(fulltext), [](const unsigned char idx) { return toupper(idx); });
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/gDwxoz)