# Is there an isdigit function (overload) which includes the negative symbol?

Tags: c++, string, numbers, digits, string-to-symbol

I'm trying to search for the beginning of a number. [`isdigit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) is there a [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) function that can include negatives in `isdigit`? So that it will match the first character of the number: "-13"?

Comment: `-` isnt really a digit, so whats wrong with `isdigit(c) || (c=='-')`?

Comment: *I'm trying to search for the beginning of a number.* -- Maybe there is no need for you to do the search, and other means of extracting the number are available.  What is the scenario where you need to search for the number?

Comment: You better use regex for such search, it will find where that numbers starts and where it stops.

Comment: Reminder:  numbers can have an optional `+` in front of them also.

Comment: Note that `+1.000.000,00` and `65,535` and `6.022x10^23` are all numbers. Will your search find them?

Comment: @TimRandall I mean if it matched +/-/`isdigit` it would... note the question is about finding *the begining* of a number.

Comment: @JonathanMee all I'm getting at is that you might want a higher-level search/parse function. Bathsheba also mentioned that accountants use `(negative_number)` format. It's complicated

Comment: @TimRandall I'm not sure what you mean... I just want to identify the first character of numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No there isn't. A *digit* is one thing that comprises a representation of a number, along with the radix, sign, decimal separator, thousands separator, and perhaps other things such as exponentation.

If `-` was emitted into `isdigit` then you could expect some folk to want `+` to be included too, and perhaps even `(` and `)` to keep the accountants happy.

So in summary, testing if something is a representation of a number is an entirely different beast to testing if a particular character is a digit.

Answer (score 2):

There is not, but it is trivial to make one

```
bool my_isdigit(unsigned char ch)
{
    return ch == '-' || std::isdigit(ch);
}
```

---

If you think about what a digit is this makes sense.  According to the standard a digit is defined as `[0-9]` and as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45469214/why-does-the-most-negative-int-value-cause-an-error-about-ambiguous-function-ove), there aren't actually any negative literals in C++. It is a positive number that gets the unary `operator -` applied to it.

Comment: Personally I'd prefer the type of `ch` to be `int`.

Comment: @Bathsheba Any particular reason for that?

Comment: Yup, cuz it's the type of `std::isdigit` innit (then you can pass EOF into your function without a nasty wraparound conversion to unsigned char).

Comment: @Bathsheba It is but *The behavior is undefined if the value of ch is not representable as unsigned char and is not equal to EOF*.  So why not just start with an `unsigned char`, instead of having to explicitly cast it?

Comment: @NathanOliver https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482246/which-tolower-in-c#comment62474094_37482246

Comment: I mean this doesn't handle EOF in it's current condition... Additionally, aren't even char equality tests generally run by first promoting both sides to an `int`?

Comment: @JonathanMee Per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21805674/do-i-need-to-cast-to-unsigned-char-before-calling-toupper-tolower-et-al) you have to cast the value you pass to these functions to an `unsigned char` which means taking an `unsigned char` in the first place, or casting the parameter, will give you the same behavior.

Comment: @NathanOliver And it finally clicks, this is the only way to force the number to be `unsigned`. Thank you. Have a +1.

Answer (score 1):

No, because [`std::isdigit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) is only for checking if a *single character* is a (decimal) digit or not, not a number.

If you want to check if a string contains a valid number (negative or not), then you can either attempt to parse it yourself (it's actually rather trivial) or use e.g. [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) (and family) which besides the conversion (that you can throw away the result of) also include verification of the input string.