# What's going on at tolower?

Tags: c++, lambda, function-pointers

I was reading this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5539302/588867

What is going on with this part: `(int (*)(int))tolower` in this line of code:

`transform(s.begin(),s.end(),s.begin(),(int (*)(int))tolower );`

If I make this function and the code works:

```
int myToLower(int c){
    return tolower(c);
}

transform(s.begin(),s.end(),s.begin(), myToLower);
```

What's plain English about this part: `(int (*)(int))`.

Comment: It's a C-style cast to a function pointer

Comment: see on [plain English decoder](https://cdecl.org/?q=%28int+%28*%29%28int%29%29)

Comment: That's an interesting page @LưuVĩnhPhúc :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see this answered in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37438120/2642059), that's a function pointer. You can read more about them here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_functions

Fundamentally this is a pointer to a function that takes in an `int` argument and returns an `int`.

---

The reason the `transform` works when using `myToLower` and not with an uncast `tolower`, is that in code is that the `tolower` function is overloaded in the `std` namespace by both the locale library's [`tolower`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/tolower) and the ctype library's [`tolower`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower). When only the function name is used as an uncast pointer no overload resolution is performed, and you'll get an error. When you cast the function pointer you're telling the compiler which overload you want.

Comment: I checked the cppreference page you gave. I can understand this: `void (*p2)(int) = f`. But from that to `(int (*)(int))tolower`, there are two steps involved: 1. definine an anonymous function pointer type `(int (*)(int))` and 2. cast `tolower` to that type. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, cast directly says compiler which of overloaded functions we want to use. I would use static_cast<> BTW.