# Use of an iterator when comparing two wstring

Tags: c++, string, compare

I am iterating through a list and through a vector. Both are filled with wstring s.

I need to compare the two strings they are pointing at and find out if "wstring1" exists in another "wstring2".

n and k are the two iterators.

When I try:

```
   wcscmp(*n,*k);
```

it fails because a const wchar t is ecpected, if I understand the error message right...

How can I check if *n = "Hello you little fellow"  contains *k="little"  ?

Case does not matter.

PS: I do not want to use the BOOST lib.

Comment: _Why_ do you not want to use boost?

Comment: Because I am not allowed to install it.... sorry

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: why do you care?

Comment: @sehe: I don't. I'm leading the OP to the part where I either prove that this is homework, or persuade him/her to cast away the shackles of pointless restrictions based on misunderstandings. Why do you care why I care?

Comment: Im 32, it's NOT homework... ;-) I'm not working on my machine right now..

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: I care because it doesn't work constructively. I know how you are _trying to_ get it to work constructively, but as it stands it just leads to repeated 'ugly comment streams' - making SO _less_ attractive IMO (besides for this question it is irrelevant, see the answers)

Comment: @sehe: How ironic that you just took up so much space with this "ugly comment stream" that doesn't even have a constructive end goal. I don't care that the best solution doesn't involve Boost: I want to teach and help language newcomers to improve. That's why I'm here. Why are _you_ here?

Comment: To lead the OP to an answer :) (and learning in the process)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
std::wstring n = L"Hello you little fello";
std::wstring k = L"little";

if ( n.find(k) != wstring::npos )
{
...
}
```

Comment: Note that you'd have to convert both strings to the same case to amke this insensitive to case differences (as the OP requested). See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313970/stl-string-to-lower-case) for how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `c_str()` method of the `std::wstring` to access the underlying storage as a null terminated wide-char string.

```
wcscmp(n->c_str(), k->c_str());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
wstring lowN(*n);
wstring lowK(*k);

std::transform(lowN.begin(), lowN.end(), lowN.begin(), ::tolower); 
std::transform(lowK.begin(), lowK.end(), lowK.begin(), ::tolower); 

if ( wstring::npos != lowN->find(lowK) ) {
    // n contains k
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two possibilities:

1: Use the native find method of wstring:

```
n->find(*k);
```

2: If you want to use wcscmp

```
wcscmp(n->c_str(),k->c_str());
```