# C++ How do I read in a file, convert each word to lower case and then cout each word?

Tags: c++

I am having trouble getting started with a program. I need to read in each word from a file, then convert it to lower case. I would like to std::cout each word after I find it. I assume I need to use Cstr() some how. I am guessing I should use something like

```
ofs.open(infile.c_str());
```

but how to lower case?

```
string[i] = tolower(string[i]);
```

then,

```
std::cout << string[i];
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313970/stl-string-to-lower-case

Answer (score 2):

Here is a complete solution:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

char my_tolower(unsigned char c)
{
    return tolower(c);
}

int main(int ac, char* av[]) {
    std::transform(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(
        ac == 1? std::cin.rdbuf(): std::ifstream(av[1]).rdbuf()),
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(),
        std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(std::cout), &my_tolower);
}
```

Comment: You probably want cctype instead of ctype.h

Comment: @ipc: Do I? Why would I? Just so `tolower()` is put into namespace `std`? The above code compiles and executes as expected. I could have included `<cctype>` and used `std::tolower(c)` but for this code it really isn't any different.

Comment: It's because `<ctype.h>` isn't in the C++ standard.

Comment: @ipc: You must have a newer version of the C++ standard than I do. Mine clearly states in D.5 "C standard library headers" [depr.c.headers] "For compatibility with the C standard library ... the C++ standard library provides
the 25 C headers, as shown in Table 154. ... <ctype.h> ..." Using something from clause D may be frowned upon but it is still a mandatory part of a standard conforming C++ implementation. This particular section is **very** unlikely to go away!

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my own question. I really didn't want to use transform, but that does work as well. If anyone else stumbles across this here is how I figured it out...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
std::ifstream theFile;
theFile.open("test.txt");
std::string theLine;
while (!theFile.eof())
{
  theFile >> theLine;       
  for (size_t j=0; j< theLine.length(); ++j)
  {
    theLine[j] = tolower(theLine[j]);
  }
  std::cout<<theLine<<std::endl;
     } 

 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int main()
{

    ofstream of("xyz.txt");

    clrscr();
    ifstream inf;
    char line;
    inf.open("abc.txt");
    int count=0;
    while(!inf.eof())
    {
        inf.get(line);
        if(line>=65 && line<=123)
        {
            cout<<line;
            line=line-32;
            of<<line;
            count++;
            cout<<line;
        }
    }
    cout<<count;
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, unless this is something like a homework assignment, it's probably easier to process one character at a time rather than one word at a time.

Yes, you have pretty much the right idea for converting to lower case, with the minor detail that you normally want to cast the input to `unsigned char` before passing it to `tolower`.

Personally, I'd avoid doing explicit input and output, and instead do a `std::transform` with a pair of `istream_iterator`s and an `ostream_iterator` for the result.

Comment: Note that you'd need to turn off skipping of whitespace (e.g. using `std::noskipws`) when using `std::istream_iterator<char>` because otherwise all spaces will be eaten. Specifically for the character type this problem can be avoided and the code be made more efficient by using `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>` (note the extra `buf`).