# Convert to Lower and Hold in Str - C++

Tags: c++, file, loops, lowercase

I'm trying to convert a string that I'm reading from a file to lowercase and hold the lowercase string in a separate string for comparison, but I want to keep the original string around for presentation, but I'm having some trouble:

```
ifstream file;
string name,
       lnStr,
       searchStr,
       lowerStr;
int lineNum = 0;
int strCount;

while(getline(file, lnStr))
    {
        lowerStr = lnStr;
        for(int i = 0; lowerStr[i] != '\0'; i++){
            lowerStr[i] = tolower(lowerStr[i]);
        }
        if(lowerStr.find(searchStr, 0) < lnStr.npos)
        {
            cout << setw(5) << ++lineNum << ":" << lnStr << endl;
            strCount++;
        }
    }
```

apparently I can't use sub[i] on strings, but it seems too much to hold it all in an array. Am I doing this the most efficiently? How can I get my lowercase string and original string separate?

Comment: possible duplicate of [STL String to lower case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313970/stl-string-to-lower-case)

Comment: You say "I can't use `sub[i]` on strings." What error message do you get when you try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no guarantee that `lowerStr[i]` will ever be `0` for any value of `i`.

```
    for(int i = 0; lowerStr[i] != '\0'; i++){
        lowerStr[i] = tolower(lowerStr[i]);
    }
```

Try this:

```
// UNTESTED
for(int i = 0; i < lowerStr.size(); i++)
    lowerStr[i] = tolower(lowerStr[i]);
```

Or, as Oli suggests:

```
std::transform(lowerStr.begin(), lowerStr.end(), lowerStr.begin(), ::tolower);
```

Ps. I can't test this fix for you because you didn't supply a complete test case. If you had, I would have.