# Could not find a match for 'std::transform..."

Tags: c++, templates, runtime, transform, lowercase

I have this weird error where the code was working before but after some time it stopped compiling.
The error is:

```
Could not find a match for 'std::transform<InputIterator,OutputIterator,UnaryOperation>(char *,char *,char *,charT (*)(charT,const locale &))' in function main()
```

and the lines which it is referring to is:

```
    string ans;
    cin>>ans;
    std::transform(ans.begin(), ans.end(), ans.begin(), ::tolower);
```

Can someone please help me out as to why this is happening?
The includes I used were:

```
#include <fstream.h>;
#include <iostream.h>;
#include <string>;
#include <time.h>;
#include <vector>;
using namespace std;
```

Thank you very much

Comment: It says that your trying to pass a `char *` as an iterator, you should take a look at the `std::transform` & `string` doc

Comment: @Samoth What's wrong with using a pointer as an iterator?

Comment: The problem is `::tolower`, not the iterators. You can't pass that function directly, because it takes two arguments. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/314163/777186

Comment: @BoBTFish I'm just reading the error message... But I read the cplusplus doc and I apologize for non-thinking answer :)

Comment: @jogojapan That's what I was thinking, but I couldn't find a `tolower` taking a `locale&` anywhere on http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=tolower&button=

Comment: I think there's a part of answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313970/stl-string-to-lower-case

Comment: @BoBTFish Yes, I am a bit confused now myself. There seem to be various `std::tolower` and `::tolower`. I had actually remembered the post I linked to and the rather complicated `bind2nd` expression used there. But when I try against GCC 4.8.1 now, the code given in the question here actually works with `::tolower` (but not `std::tolower`).

Comment: Ah ha, found it: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/tolower
Has someone recently added `#include <locale>` to your code?

Comment: @BoBTFish I think you got the basis for an answer there..

Comment: Nop, at locale was not added.

Comment: You should post a complete (but minimal) example, showing the includes you use, as well as any using directives and/or declarations.

Comment: Its funny lol @ Samoth, I had to use that link and the unsuggested ans by no 198 which worked. But I would like to know why my code doesn't work.

Comment: `<fstream.h>` et al are non-standard. Use `<fstream>`, `<iostream>` and  `<ctime>`.

Answer (score 2):

If what you say, that this worked up until very recently, I must assume that someone has introduced a small change elsewhere in the code that breaks things.
Now, this works:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string s1 {"Hello"}, s2;
    std::transform(
            std::begin(s1),
            std::end(s1),
            std::back_inserter(s2),
            ::tolower);
    std::cout << s2 << '\n';
}
```

I.e. it prints `hello`.
If I add these two lines at the top:

```
#include <locale>
using std::tolower;
```

I get a similar error to you (not identical). This is because it brings [this version of `tolower`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/tolower) into scope.
To get back the "proper" version (assuming you did mean the version in the `cctype` header?) you can use `static_cast` to pick the one you want:

```
// ...

#include <locale>
using std::tolower;

int main()
{
    std::string s1 {"Hello"}, s2;
    std::transform(
            std::begin(s1),
            std::end(s1),
            std::back_inserter(s2),
            static_cast<int(*)(int)>(::tolower)); // Cast picks the correct fn.
    std::cout << s2 << '\n';
}
```

Edit: I have to say, I'm confused as to why you are picking up that version specifically, rather than getting an ambiguous error. But I can't guess exactly what has been changed in your code...

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. Maybe you forgot to include `<algorithm>`.

It should work this way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   string ans;
    cin>>ans;
    std::transform(ans.begin(), ans.end(), ans.begin(), ::tolower);
   cout << ans;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Indeed he should `#include <algorithm>` but the error message suggests the compiler does know the signature of `transform`, so it is being picked up somehow or other (inside some other `include` I suppose).

Comment: I tried it, and it worked for me that way. Maybe on your compiler you have to include something else for `tolower`?