# C++: Find matching characters in character array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, search

How do I implement a c++ script to search a group of characters from an character array.The search characters are not case sensitive.For an example, I key in "aBc" and the character array has "abcdef" and it is a hit and shows the found.

This is my script,don't know what is wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  char charArr1[]="abcdefghi";
  char inputArr[20];

  cin>>inputArr;
  charArr1.find("abc");
}
```

I recevied this error.
request for member 'find' in 'charArr1', which is of non-class type 'char [10]

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't use `std::string`? This would be a lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to convert the input to lower case, and
use `std::search`:

```
struct ToLower
{
    bool operator()( char ch ) const
    {
        return ::tolower( static_cast<unsigned char>( ch ) );
    }
};

std::string reference( "abcdefghi" );
std::string toSearch;
std::cin >> toSearch;
std::transform( toSearch.begin(), toSearch.end(), toSearch.begin(), ToLower() );
std::string::iterator results
    = std::search( reference.begin(), reference.end(),
                   toSearch.begin(), toSearch.end() );
if ( results != reference.end() ) {
    //  found
} else {
    //  not found
}
```

The `ToLower` class should be in your toolkit; if you do any
text processing, you'll use it a lot.  You'll notice the type
conversion; this is necessary to avoid undefined behavior due to
the somewhat special interface of `::tolower`.  (Depending on
the type of text processing you do, you may want to change it to
use the `ctype` facet in `std::locale`.  You'd also avoid the
funny cast, but the class itself will have to carry some excess
bagage to keep a pointer to the facet, and to keep it alive.)

Answer (score 3):

1. copy your inputs and convert them to lower case (see [How to convert std::string to lower case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313970/stl-string-to-lower-case))
2. perform usual search (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/)

Comment: Sorry for the spam, I am new here. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: The answer in the link you post is incorrect, and invokes undefined behavior (at least on many platforms).  You cannot call `::tolower` with a `char`.