# How to order strings case-insensitively (not lexicographically)?

Tags: c++, string

I'm attempting to order a list input from a file alphabetically (not lexicographically).  So, if the list were:

C
d
A
b

I need it to become:
A
b
C
d

Not the lexicographic ordering:
A
C
b
d

I'm using string variables to hold the input, so I'm looking for some way to modify the strings I'm comparing to all uppercase or lowercase, or if there's some easier way to force an alphabetic comparison, please impart that wisdom.  Thanks!

I should also mention that we are limited to the following libraries for this assignment: iostream, iomanip, fstream, string, as well as C libraries, like cstring, cctype, etc.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313970/stl-string-to-lower-case) looks great for what you need, but the arbitrary restriction of libraries seems to force you write a for loop with `toupper`/`tolower` to do the job.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that, but it looks like I'd need access to the algorithm or boost libraries to make use of those suggestions.  It looks like I'm just going to have to defeat this problem via some very tedious method of character extraction and toppering for each string.

Comment: Note on vocabulary: alphabetical = lexicographic (or, more precisely, lexicographic order is a generalisation of alphabetical order). What you want is known as “case insensitive”.

Comment: Thanks for the vocab tip.  In that case, I think what I need is "case insensitive" ordering.  The lexicographic ASCII ordering places uppercase letters before lowercase letters.  So, 'Z' comes before 'a'.  But I need to sort a list so that 'a' comes before 'Z'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It looks like I'm just going to have to defeat this problem via some very tedious method of character extraction and toppering for each string.

Converting the individual strings to upper case and comparing them is not made particularly worse by being restricted from using algorithm, iterator, etc. The comparison logic is about four lines of code. Even though it would be nice not to have to write those four lines having to write a sorting algorithm is far more difficult and tedious. (Well, assuming that the usual C version of `toupper` is acceptable in the first place.)

Below I show a simple `strcasecmp()` implementation and then put it to use in a complete program which uses restricted libraries. The implementation of `strcasecmp()` itself doesn't use restricted libraries.

```
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>

void toupper(std::string &s) {
  for (char &c : s)
    c = std::toupper(c);
}

bool strcasecmp(std::string lhs, std::string rhs) {
  toupper(lhs); toupper(rhs);
  return lhs < rhs;
}

// restricted libraries used below

#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

// Example usage:
//  > ./a.out <<< "C d A b"
//  A b C d
int main() {
  std::vector<std::string> input;
  std::string word;
  while(std::cin >> word) {
    input.push_back(word);
  }

  std::sort(std::begin(input), std::end(input), strcasecmp);
  std::copy(std::begin(input), std::end(input),
            std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " "));
  std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the for-each syntax.  Does for( char &c : s ) mean "for each character in the string s"?

Comment: @Caulibrot Yes. It's C++11 syntax and it does the same thing as `for (int i=0; i<s.size(); ++i) s[i] = std::toupper(s[i]);`

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to modify the strings before sorting. You can sort them in place with a case-insensitive single character comparator and [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort):

```
bool case_insensitive_cmp(char lhs, char rhs) {
  return ::toupper(static_cast<unsigned char>(lhs) < 
         ::toupper(static_cast<unsigned char>(rhs);
}

std::string input = ....;
std::sort(input.begin(), input.end(), case_insensitive_cmp);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
std::vector<string> vec {"A", "a", "lorem", "Z"};    
std::sort(vec.begin(),
          vec.end(),
          [](const string& s1, const string& s2) -> bool {
            return strcasecmp(s1.c_str(), s2.c_str()) < 0 ? true : false;
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use strcasecmp() as comparison function in qsort().

Comment: Is strcasecmp() part of any of the libraries mentioned above?  When I Google it, it looks like it's not part of any of the standard libraries, meaning it's off limits for my assignment--which is a real bummer.

Comment: Correct, `strcasecmp` is POSIX, not part of the C++ standard.

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure how to write it, but what you want to do is convert the strings to lower or uppercase.

If the strings are in an array to begin with, you would run through the list, and save the indexes in order in an (int) array.

Comment: I'm holding them in variables of type string.  I was hoping to find a simple way to force alphabetic ordering.  I know I could do something like use the at() function to extract characters from the string and toupper() them, but that seems like a lot of work and complication.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just comparing letters, then a terrible hack which will work is to mask the upper two bits off each character.  Then upper and lower case letters fall on top of each other.

Comment: By mask, do you mean to use a bitwise mask and switch the bits to the opposite values?

Comment: Yes you could do `c = 0x40 | ( c & 0x1f ) ;`