# How to use (or not to use?) goto in a else - if

Tags: c++

Every time I use `if` with `goto` to bypass a process and to go directly to quit, it doesn't bypass something with a command but it just goes to the end. Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  string k;
  cout <<"What would you like to do ?\n"<<"Continue or Exit\n";
  cin >> k;
  if (k = "exit","Exit") goto s;
  else (k = "Continue","continue");
  cout << "You continued...";
  s:
  return 0
}
```

The problem is that even if you type "exit" or "continue" it just simply closes.
Can someone see the problem? Also, how could I avoid using the goto?

Comment: Use `break` instead of `goto`

Comment: Qhy are you using `goto` - left that in the 80's

Comment: How did you even manage to compile this?

Comment: You could **transform** the string to lower case, then make only one comparsion for each word: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313970/stl-string-to-lower-case

Answer (score 4):

The first `if` is always `true`, since after the assignment, the test on the RHS of the comma operator will be `true`.

Your simple program doesn't warrant the use of `goto`. Also overkill would be my preference for handling such tasks, though: a function table.

I finished off an example. We start with a simple callback class. The callback interface comes with a default implementation that complains about the input.

```
struct Callback {
    virtual ~Callback () {}
    virtual void operator () (std::string k) const {
        std::cout << "Unrecognized input: " << k << '\n';
    }
};
```

This part defines the function table data structure, declares an API to initialize one, and the driver code that invokes the callback:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, const Callback *> CallbackMap;

static void init_table (CallbackMap &cbmap);

static void invoke_table (const CallbackMap &cbmap, std::string k)
{
    CallbackMap::const_iterator i = cbmap.find(k);
    if (i != cbmap.end()) (*i->second)(k);
    else Callback()(k);
}

int main ()
{
    CallbackMap cbmap;
    std::string k;
    init_table(cbmap);
    std::cout << "What would you like to do?\nContinue or Exit\n";
    std::cin >> k;
    invoke_table(cbmap, k);
    return 0;
}
```

The individual callback implementations are implemented as singletons with this helper macro:

```
#define CONST_SINGLETON(Name) \
    public: \
        static const Name & instance () { \
            static const Name one; \
            return one; \
        } \
    private: \
        Name () {} \
        Name (const Name &); \
        void operator = (const Name &)
```

And each callback implementation does the simple action that was presented in your sample program:

```
class ExitCallback : public Callback {
    void operator () (std::string) const { std::exit(0); }
    CONST_SINGLETON(ExitCallback);
};

class ContinueCallback : public Callback {
    void operator () (std::string) const {
        std::cout << "You continued...\n";
    }
    CONST_SINGLETON(ContinueCallback);
};
```

The initialization routine populates the function table with the string that corresponds to the appropriate callback:

```
static void init_table (CallbackMap &cbmap)
{
    static struct { const char *s; const Callback *cb; } init[] = {
        { "exit", &ExitCallback::instance() },
        { "Exit", &ExitCallback::instance() },
        { "continue", &ContinueCallback::instance() },
        { "Continue", &ContinueCallback::instance() },
        { 0, 0 }
    };
    for (int i = 0; init[i].s; ++i) {
        cbmap[init[i].s] = init[i].cb;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

**1)** Don't use `goto` here : it is almost never appropriate to use it in modern C++ code.

**2)** Use `==` to compare strings (`=` is used for `string` assignments )

```
 if (k == "exit","Exit") 
      ^^^^
    //Here

 else (k == "Continue","continue")
      ^^^^
   // And here
```

**3)** `,` is not an "and" operator, use :

```
if (k == "exit" || k == "Exit")
```

**4)** You have enclosing braces that are useless, indent your code to properly see which block is *really* needed.

Comment: And `if (k == "exit" || k == "Exit")`, and no random braces that are unmatched.

Comment: "Don't use goto"  A better statement would be:  goto is not appropriate here, it is useful only in the rarest of circumstances.

Comment: Yes I agree, I clarified.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `else if (...)` now that it's not an assignment?

Answer (score 3):

You need to learn how to use the debugger and you need to learn more about C++

```
if (k = "exit","Exit") goto s;   //VERY WRONG
```

does not mean what you want:

- the `=` of `k="exit"` is understood as an assignment
- the comma is understood as the [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator)

At least code `if (k == "exit" || k == "Exit")` and [avoid `goto`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goto#Criticism_and_decline) when possible.

Also, enable all warnings (and debug info). Perhaps your compiler could warn you.

I would suggest you to *read some source code* from [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) (e.g. on [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/) or elsewhere). That will teach you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Proper indenting and style will help you see some of your efforts.

First, I highly recommend transforming the string to either lower or upper case.  This eliminates the need to check all permutations of upper and lower case letters in the string:

```
  cout << "What would you like to do ?\n"
       << "Continue or Exit\n";
  cin >> k;
  std::transform(k.begin(), k.end(), k.begin(), tolower);
```

To exit the `main` function, `return` a value, such as EXIT_SUCCESS or EXIT_FAILURE.

```
  if (k == "exit")
  {
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
  } // No goto's necessary
  // The code continues here.
```

Remember '=' is assignment, '==' is comparison.

There is no need for comparing for "continue" because it does that "automatically" if the response is not "exit".

**Using `goto`**
Usage of `goto` in this instance is **not recommended**.
If you really must use goto, you will need more than one label.

```
int main(void)
{
  string k;

top_of_loop:  // Label for your goto
  cout << "What would you like to do ?\n"
       <<"Continue or Exit\n";
  cin >> k;
  std::transform(k.begin(), k.end(), k.begin(), tolower);

  if (k == "exit")
  {
    goto end_of_program;
  }
  // Execution continues here automatically.

  else
  {
    if (k == "continue")
    {
       goto program_continuation;
    }
    else
    {
       cout << "Unknown response, try again.\n";
       goto top_of_loop;
    }
  }
program_continuation:
  cout << "You continued...";
  goto top_of_loop;

end_of_program:
  return 0
}
```

**As a `while` loop**

```
  cout << "What would you like to do ?\n"
       <<"Continue or Exit\n";
  cin >> k;
  std::transform(k.begin(), k.end(), k.begin(), tolower);
  while (k != "exit")
  {
    // Your program stuff here.
    cout << "Program continued.\n";

    // Prompt the User again.
    cout << "\n"
         << "What would you like to do ?\n"
         << "Continue or Exit\n";
    cin >> k;
    std::transform(k.begin(), k.end(), k.begin(), tolower);
  }
  return 0; // Exit main().
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code reflects your intentions, but those intentions are not written in C++. They are a valid C++ program - it compiles, of course - but what you meant isn't what you've written.

Here it is, fixed to do what you wished to do.

```
int main()
{
  string k;
  cout << "What would you like to do ?\nContinue or Exit" << endl;
  cin >> k;
  if (! (k == "exit" || k == "Exit")) {
    if (k == "Continue" || k == "continue") {
      cout << "You continued...";
    }
  }
  return 0
}
```

You could also do:

```
int main()
{
  string k;
  cout << "What would you like to do ?\nContinue or Exit" << endl;
  cin >> k;
  if (k == "exit" or k == "Exit") return 0;
  if (k == "Continue" or k == "continue") {
    cout << "You continued...";
  }
  return 0
}
```

The changes are as follows:

1. To check if one of a multitude of conditions are true, use the logical *or* operator to join the tests. The operator is written as `||` or, simply enough, `or`.
2. The comparison operator is `==`. The operator you've used, `=`, is an assignment operator. It performs the assignment, its resulting value is the assigned value.
3. The comma operator separates multiple expression to be evaluated. Its resulting value is the *last* expression, even though all expressions are evaluated. For example, the value of `(1, 2, 3)` is `3`.