# find an word in vector<string> cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I have an vector word_list, and i want to find an word in word_list. I use function

```
bool Mylayer::existWord(vector<string> word_list, string word)
{ 
    if (std::lower_bound(word_list.begin(), word_list.end(), word) != word_list.end())
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

but it find not exactly. Can some one tell me why ?

Comment: Is your word_list sorted?

Comment: std::lower_bound expects ordered range

Comment: If you're trying to find an exact word, perhaps you should use `std::find`.

Comment: BTW you should pass `vector` by const reference.

Comment: Why do you use member functions that act only on parameters? C++ allows non-member functions

Comment: word_list sorted. I use std::find but it's not exact

Answer (score 7):

- Your method should look like:

  ```
  bool Mylayer::existWord(
      const std::vector<std::string>& words,
      const std::string& word) const
  { 
      return std::find(words.begin(), words.end(), word) != words.end();
  }
  ```
- If your `vector` is sorted, you may use `std::binary_search`:

  ```
  bool Mylayer::existWord(
      const std::vector<std::string>& words,
      const std::string& word) const
  { 
      assert(std::is_sorted(words.begin(), words.end())); // debug check
      return std::binary_search(words.begin(), words.end(), word);
  }
  ```
- If your collection is sorted without duplicate, you may use a `std::set<std::string>`
  and your method becomes:

  ```
  bool Mylayer::existWord(
      const std::set<std::string>& words,
      const std::string& word) const
  { 
      return words.count(word) != 0;
  }
  ```

Comment: i have a question: does Find function distinguish  uppercase and lowercase ?

Comment: @MrVy: as `std::string`, so yes. An easy way to manage that is to *lower case* all strings (see [stl-string-to-lower-case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313970/stl-string-to-lower-case) for how to do that). An other way is to use `find_if` with a predicate.

Answer (score -1):

you may try using find

ideone link: http://ideone.com/bgFZwU

```
bool existWord(vector<string> word_list, string word) {
    vector<string>:: iterator it;

    it= find(word_list.begin(), word_list.end(), word);
    if(it== word_list.end()) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```