# My function's return is printing to the console and it will only work every other time I call it C++

Tags: c++, function, methods, return

I was just playing around with c++ and decided to make a text based RPG. I created a method to get info from the user and change it to lower case. This is the function:

```
std::string getInfo_ToLower(std::string whatToSay) {

    std::string a = "";
    std::cout << whatToSay << std::endl;
    getline(std::cin, a);

    for(int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++){
        a[i] = putchar(tolower(a[i]));
    }
    return a;
};
```

Im working on Xcode if that helps. So, is there any reason that this method would only work every other time I called it and is there a reason my "return a;" is printing to the console?

Thanks.

Comment: As a replacement for the tolower loop, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313970/how-to-convert-stdstring-to-lower-case . Try to avoid C-style function if you want somewhat "pure" C++.

Comment: Thank you Praetorian. That fixed the issue. Still have the weird problem with it only working every other time I call it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code calls `putchar` as it goes through the string `a`, but the result is *buffered*. If you want it to become visible right away, add call of `fflush`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++){
    a[i] = putchar(tolower(a[i]));
}
fflush(stdout);
return a;
```

Note that the way you do printing and conversion at the same time is highly non-intuitive. You would be better off printing the result separately, like this:

```
// There are better ways to do this, but just to illustrate the point
// let's keep the loop in place
for(int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++){
    a[i] = tolower(a[i]);
}
cout << a << flush;
return a;
```

Comment: :-) Oh, just saw your edit avoiding putchar. flush shouldn't be necessary either, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Why is it necessary to use put char?
Wouldn't cout do it better?

```
for(int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++){
    a[i] = tolower(a[i]);
}
std::cout << a <<std::endl;
```

Comment: Yeah. I'm very new to programming and i misunderstood the use of putchar. I took it out and it fixed the problem with it printing to the console when i didn't want it to.