# C++ help related to Upper and Lower cases

Tags: c++

I want the code to search for a word mid sentence and see if its first letter is lower case.

If it is, than it makes it upper case. For example: John hates using c++ daily, and it would change the C in c++ to uppercase.

Here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

ifstream in_stream;
ofstream out_stream;

int main()
{
    in_stream.open("in.dat");
    out_stream.open("out.dat");
    char s[256];
    in_stream>>s;
    s[0] = tolower(s[0]);
    out_stream<<s;

    in_stream.close();
    out_stream.close();
    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is anser is here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313970/how-to-convert-stdstring-to-lower-case

Comment: Why are there blank links throughout your code? And no indentation? And why are you using `char` arrays?

Comment: @teivaz does not mention how to find the middle of the string... but I'm sure that is a different answer

Comment: Please more clearly explain the intended behavior of your code.

Comment: Why character arrays instead of std::string?

Comment: How exactly should your code know that it has to convert to uppercase the `c` of `c++`? The full string `John hates using c++ daily` comes from in.dat, but what about the letter that must be capitalized? It is the first of the chosen word, but *how* is the chosen word chosen?

Comment: If you are converting to *upper* case, why are you using `tolower`?

Answer (score 1):

Redefine `s` to be of type `std::string`

```
std::string wordOfInterest = "c++" // Change as per your needs
std::string::size_type pos = s.find(wordOfInterest); // Index at which the word of interest starts
if (pos != std::string::npos) s[pos] = toupper(s[pos]); // Updating the value at index with its upper case counterpart
```

Comment: He wants the middle word... not find function

Comment: @SethKitchen I dont think so, "a word mid sentence" sounds like somewhere in the sentence, not necessarily the central word