# How to convert from utf32 to Unicode String

Tags: c++, string, unicode, type-conversion

I have been looking around for some time for this question but always end up with something different.

I have the following UTF-32 string: `std::u32string utf32s = U"जि";`
And I would like to convert to an UnicodeString: `UnicodeString ustr;`

I am using the ICU 65.1 library in C++ to deal with Unicode String for normalization and composition, I found the following [link](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings#TOC-Using-UTF-32-strings-with-ICU) which describe in a very poor way the conversion between strings. Especially the following description:

1. Conversion of whole strings: `u_strFromUTF32()` and `u_strFromUTF32()`
   in `ustring.h`.
2. Access to code points is trivial and does not require any macros.
3. Using a UTF-32 converter with all of the ICU conversion APIs in
   ucnv.h, including ones with an "Algorithmic" suffix.
4. UnicodeString has `fromUTF32()` and `toUTF32()` methods.

The alternative I have found is the following template function:

```
template <typename T>
void fromUTF32(const std::u32string& source, std::basic_string<T, std::char_traits<T>, std::allocator<T>>& result)
{
    wstring_convert<codecvt_utf8_utf16<T>, T> convertor;
    result = convertor.from_bytes(source);
}
```

This function anyhow seams not to recognize UnicodeString as valid input. 
 More in general, given a string (wstring, string, u16string ...) how to create a template function to get it as a Unicode String ?

Many thanks !

Comment: UnicodeString is not a standard C++ type.

Comment: What does `codecvt_utf8_utf16` have to do with utf32?

Comment: @n.m. yes, this is why I am working with ICU library (as I linked): for instance by including: `#include "unicode/unistr.h"`

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin you are right, this is why I am asking how to change that template, if possible

Comment: UTF-8, UTF-16 and UTF-32 are all Unicode encodings. You haven't told us us what encoding `UnicodeString` uses.

Comment: @RichardCritten if it's from ICU, more than likely it uses UTF-16.

Comment: @RichardCritten from this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34513831/choosing-encoding-for-icuunicodestring

the answer state: `UnicodeString represents a UTF-16 encoded string.`

Comment: `auto ustr = UnicodeString::fromUTF32(utf32s.c_str(), -1);` doesn't work?

Comment: @Shawn than you for help, but I got `no suitable conversion function from "std::u32string" to "const UChar32 *" exists`

Comment: Might have to cast from `char32_t*` to `UChar32 *` too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unicode/unistr.h>
#include <unicode/ustream.h>

int main() {
  std::u32string utf32s = U"जि";
  auto ustr = UnicodeString::fromUTF32(
      reinterpret_cast<const UChar32 *>(utf32s.c_str()), utf32s.size());
  std::cout << ustr << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

```
$ g++ u32.cpp $(icu-config --cxxflags --ldflags --ldflags-icuio)                               
$ ./a.out
जि
```

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use [`icu::UnicodeString::fromUTF32`](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/released/icu4c/classicu_1_1UnicodeString.html#a7d334d126367b32733d08173dd4a3d21):

```
icu::UnicodeString asUnicodeString(std::u32string const& s) {
    static_assert(sizeof(std::u32string::value_type) == sizeof(UChar32), "");
    static_assert(alignof(std::u32string::value_type) == alignof(UChar32), "");
    return icu::UnicodeString::fromUTF32(reinterpret_cast<UChar32 const*>(s.data()), s.size());
}
```

Comment: than you Maxim but when I try it I get: `argument of type "char32_t *" is incompatible with parameter of type "const UChar32 *" `