# 'colon' and 'auto' in for loop c++? need some help understanding the syntax

Tags: c++, c++11

I need some explanation for the following c++ syntax:

```
for(const auto& ioDev : deviceList)
```

given that:

```
std::vector<Device *> deviceList
```

Specifically, I am confused about ':' and the usage of 'auto'?

Comment: Google "c++ auto" and "range-based for".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As described in the answer by Chad, your for-loop iterates over your `vector`, using its `begin` and `end` iterators. That is the behavior of the colon `:` syntax.

Regarding your `const auto &` syntax: you should imagine what code comes out of it:

```
// "i" is an iterator
const auto& ioDev = *i;
```

The expression `*i` is (a reference to) the type of elements in the container: `Device *`. This is the deduced type of `auto`. Because you have `const &` appended to your `auto`, the variable `ioDev` is a `const` reference to the deduced type (a pointer), as if it were declared this way:

```
const Device *& ioDev = *i;
```

It seems needlessly complicated; if you need just normal iteration (and not e.g. manipulating the address of the pointer, which I think is highly unlikely), use a plain unmodified `auto`:

```
for (auto ioDev : deviceList)
```

or an explicit type:

```
for (Device* ioDev : deviceList)
```

Answer (score 34):

This is a range based for loop, it has the same basic behavior of:

```
for(auto it = deviceList.begin(); it != deviceList.end(); ++it)
{
   const auto& ioDev = *it;
}
```

The range based for loop has quickly become one of my favorite constructs, it's terse and when you need to iterate an entire range, works as well (and as efficiently) as possible.

If you need the other constructs of a typical for loop (say to exit early in some case), then range-based for isn't for that use case.

Comment: Exiting a range-based for loop due to a particular condition can still easily be accomplished by using `break`. IMHO an additional `if` statement in the loop body is still much cleaner than constructing a "traditional" for loop with a particular stop condition. In my experience, the need for a "traditional" for loop mostly arises when the container is mutated in the loop body.

Answer (score 2):

The "new" `for` loop simply iterates over all the elements of `deviceList`. In each iteration of the body of the loop, `ioDev` is a const reference to each of the elments of `deviceList`, successively.

As to the type of `ioDev`: it is of type `Device *const &`, as you can see in the following:

```
#include <vector>                                                                                                                                                                                            
#include <type_traits>


using namespace std;


int main()
{
    vector<int *> v;

    for(const auto &r: v)
    {
        static_assert(is_same<decltype(r), int *const &>::value, "wrong type");
    }
}
```