# STL library ostream operator and auto iterator

Tags: c++, algorithm, list, stl, splice

While I was studying c++ STL library, i came across this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ostr, const std::list<int>& list)
{
    for (auto &i : list) {
        ostr << " " << i;
    }
    return ostr;
}

int main ()
{
    std::list<int> list1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    std::list<int> list2 = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };

    auto it = list1.begin();
    std::advance(it, 2);

    list1.splice(it, list2);

    std::cout << "list1: " << list1 << "\n";
    std::cout << "list2: " << list2 << "\n";

    list2.splice(list2.begin(), list1, it, list1.end());

    std::cout << "list1: " << list1 << "\n";
    std::cout << "list2: " << list2 << "\n";
}
```

I can understand the basic concept, but im confused in this code:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ostr, const std::list<int>& list)
    {
        for (auto &i : list) {
            ostr << " " << i;
        }
        return ostr;
    }
```

can someone exlpain me, what this ostream& and this auto &i , means ? and generally these lines of code.

Comment: [`auto`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto), [`std::ostream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35490236/colon-and-auto-in-for-loop-c-need-some-help-understanding-the-syntax