# What does for(auto &it: a) mean?

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector, operators

I'm a newbie and learning how to use the c++ language in a more flexible way.

In a contest problem I have seen someone write code like this:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
#ifdef _DEBUG
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
//  freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
#endif
    
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while (t--) {
        int n;
        cin >> n;
        vector<int> a(n);
        for (auto &it : a) cin >> it;
        sort(a.begin(), a.end());
        bool ok = true;
        for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
            ok &= (a[i] - a[i - 1] <= 1);
        }
        if (ok) cout << "YES" << endl;
        else cout << "NO" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm assuming that this line `vector<int> a(n);` declares a vector and allocates space.

My doubts are:

1. I'm confused on how this for `(auto &it : a) cin >> it;` works.
2. I also don't understand the expression `ok &= (a[i] - a[i - 1] <= 1);`.

Comment: It's a range-based for loop: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

Comment: Also this type of question is better answered by reading [a good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['colon' and 'auto' in for loop c++? need some help understanding the syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35490236/colon-and-auto-in-for-loop-c-need-some-help-understanding-the-syntax)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1.**

```
for (auto &it : a) cin >> it
```

means you are taking the input of vector `a`.

It's similar to:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < n; i++){
    cin>>a[i]; 
}
```

The auto keyword specifies that the type of the variable that is being declared will be automatically deducted from its initializer. So here `it` takes the references of `a[i]` and works instead of `a[i]` as `it`.

**2.**

```
(a[i] - a[i - 1] <= 1)
```

results boolean 1 (if condition is true) or 0 (if condition is false).

```
ok &= (a[i] - a[i - 1] <= 1)
```

means `ok = ok & 1` or `ok = ok & 0`, depending on the condition true or false.

Comment: got it! the & sign confused me, otherwise i think i understood it

Comment: & is bitwise logical and operation like 12 & 5 . 12->1100 and 5=>0101 so a&b = 0100 i.e 4

Comment: aaand can you tell me why i get different result when i use different method of finding the min element ? https://pastebin.com/DBd594vb

Comment: both method is correct to find minimum element. can you let me know the case for what the result is different

Comment: yes https://codeforces.com/contest/1399/problem/B

Comment: ok the problem is when you used sort() function the order of the vector had changed. In the given problem order should not be changed. But when you use *min_element()  function it will give you min element without sorting. Hope you clear :)

Answer (score 2):

The syntax:

```
for (auto& it : a)
```

is called a range-based loop.

It's used to manipulate each element given in `a` array or vector and the type of the element will be equivalent to the type of the `a`.

OTOH, the `&` states that anything modified to any of the element `it` in `a` will be originally replaced and no copy will be made for temporary use (i.e. by reference).

In short words, if an element has value `3` and if you change it to `5`, the original array or vector will get affected.

---

```
ok &= (a[i] - a[i - 1] <= 1);
```

is a equivalent to isn't a reference to operator, it's bitwise in this context:

```
ok = ok & (a[i] - a[i - 1] <= 1);
```

Since the type of `ok` is a `bool`, only `true (1)` or `false (0)` could be held.

Comment: i get that part now, but what about the ok&?

Comment: @Maisha `ok ?= (exp)` is equivalent to bitwise `ok ? (exp)`.

Answer (score 2):

you have a `vector<T> x` then you want to iteate over every element

you could do in the old "c" style something like:

```
for (int i=0; i<x.size(); ++i)
```

but you could also use a range-based loop doing:

```
for (T i:x)
```

with the consequence that `i` is a copy taken from the element in the vector
so if you need instead the reference you do:

```
for (T& i:x)
```

AND here the answer to your code, since c++11 you can infer the type of i ***auto***-matically
ergo the syntax

```
for (auto& i : x)
```

Comment: It is not necessary to mention C++11 for `auto`, the range based loop wasn't available before C++11 too.

Comment: @mch am mentioning auto because it will work only after c++11, but thanks :)!