# How to transfer text from one dimension of array to another in lowercase in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

So basically I have a string array called QandA[2][55].

`QandA[0][0-55]` contains questions (0-55 is the range)

`QandA[1][0-55]` contains the answer to these questions

Now I have to make a loop that will transfer all the strings from `QandA[1][1-55]` to `QandA[2][1-55]` in the same order but lowercase. I have tried this code but it doesn't seem to work. I've also checked that the string arrays work by using a loop to cout all the strings from 0-55. My code that has an error is shown below.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 55; i++) {
    QandA[2][i] = tolower(QandA[1][i]);
}
```

This gives me an error saying "No suitable conversion from std::string to int exists" which I don't understand because I assumed tolower was for string values, not int.

Comment: Perhaps it was a mistake, but you said that your array is `QandA[2][55]`, but then you try to access the third index of `QandA`, which doesn't exist, since `QandA` has a size of 2 (and each index of `QandA` has a size of 55).

Comment: To lower returns a char

Comment: Error lists `std::string`, therefore this is c++ not c so i have removed the c tag.

Answer (score 1):

Although your code will likely have other issues (eg, out of bounds access in the first dimension of `QandA`), the problem you are seeing here is that [`std::tolower`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower) is supposed to take a single character:

```
char lowerChar = std::tolower('C');
```

If you want to make a whole string lower case you need to do it per character in the string. There are plenty of ways to do it, for eg. [How to convert std::string to lower case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313970/how-to-convert-stdstring-to-lower-case)

Taking from this answer, your code code be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 55; i++) 
{
    QandA[2][i] = std::transform(QandA[1][i].begin(), 
                                 QandA[1][i].end(), 
                                 QandA[1][i].begin(), 
                                 ::tolower);
}
```

Also remember that to accomplish this the declaration of `QandA` must be:

```
std::string QandA[3][55];
```

although if you can use `c++11`, prefer:

```
std::array<std::array<std::string, 55>, 3> QandA;
```

for more features and better everything.