# If else statement using upper and lower case letters

Tags: c++

So I am having troubles. My professor wants me to write a basic program that adds up costs and outputs the rate for a cable company based if its a residential package or a business package using if else statements.
The only issue I am having is he wants the user to be able to input either 'R' or 'r' upper case or lower base, same with 'B' or 'b'.

I was doing this

```
if(customer_Type=='R' || 'r')
```

but it was not moving to the next else if statement if I used anything other than R or r. With the code beneath the program works exactly how I want it to but just without the lower case letters

```
cout<<"Welcome to Cable Company billing procedure.\n";
cout<<"Enter your account number : ";
cin>>customer_Account_Number;
cout<<"Enter your customer type (residential input R or business input B) : ";
cin>>customer_Type;
```

-

```
    if(customer_Type=='R') // If residential
{
    cout<<"How many premium channels have you subscribed to?\n";
    cin>>num_Of_Prem_Channels;
    amount_Due = ResBillProcFee + ResBasicServCost + ResCostPremChannels * num_Of_Prem_Channels;
    cout<<"Your residential bill is $"<<amount_Due<<endl;
}
else if(customer_Type=='B')
{
    cout<<"Enter number of premium channels\n";
    cin>>num_Of_Prem_Channels;
    cout<<"Enter number of basic service connections\n";
    cin>>num_Of_Basic_Service_Connections;

    if (num_Of_Basic_Service_Connections <= 10)
    {
        amount_Due = BusBillProcFee + BusBasicServCost + num_Of_Prem_Channels * BusCostPremChannel;
    }
    else
    {
        amount_Due = BusBillProcFee + BusBasicServCost + (num_Of_Basic_Service_Connections - 10) * BusBasicConCost + num_Of_Prem_Channels * BusCostPremChannel;
    }
    cout<<"Your bill is :"<<BusBillProcFee + BusBasicServCost + (num_Of_Prem_Channels * BusCostPremChannel);
}


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Convert all (relevant) input to lowercase and then you only have one case to check. `customer_Type` here.

Comment: Easy way is to convert the input to upper case on entry. Your current code is incorrect.

Comment: Try `if((customer_Type=='R') || (customer_Type =='r'))`. `if(customer_Type=='R' || 'r')` is equals to `if(customer_Type=='R' || true)`. If you convert the input to upper camel, you should refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313970/how-to-convert-stdstring-to-lower-case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to check for each character in `if` condition with OR `||` operator:

```
if ( customer_Type == 'R' || customer_Type == 'r' )
{
    // ...
}
```

Otherwise, you can use [std::tolower](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower) or [std::toupper](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper) to make the input characters uniform for comparisons with lowercase or uppercase letters respectively.

For example for lowercase comparison:

```
if ( std::tolower( customer_Type ) == 'r' )
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example! I had no idea about that nifty toupper/tolower command

Comment: @IsakAngerstig: You're welcome! The documentation links are there also. You may go through those to build an understanding. And, those are *functions*, not commands. :)