# Inserting a character in a string

Tags: c++, string, c++14

I have a string `name2`. I want to remove the capital characters in it and put lowercase instead.

Input:`Car` Output:`car`

Here is my loop code:-

```
 if(isupper(name2.at(i))) {
           string tem=to_string(tolower(name2.at(i)));
            name2.erase(i,1);
            name2.insert(i,tem);
        }
```

`i` is just the loop variable.

However , here is my input vs output

Input:`Sushant`  Output:`115ushant`

It is giving some sort of ASCII equivalent ouput , I suppose.
How do I fix this?

Comment: You can check how to make lowercase from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313970/how-to-convert-stdstring-to-lower-case

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert std::string to lower case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313970/how-to-convert-stdstring-to-lower-case)

Comment: You don't need to erase/insert, you can just set the value directly: `name2[i] = tolower(name[i])`. I suppose you are iterating over the string, are you (`for(size_t i = 0; i < name2.length; ++i)`)? Then you won't need range checking access (`at(i)`), you *know* you are in range, so prefer the more efficient non-checking index operator (`name2[i]`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, `to_string` interprets the result of `tolower` as an integer. So what you see inserted in your string is the ASCII value of 's' (115). To fix this, there is no need to convert to string, just use characters directly:

```
char c = tolower(name.at(i));
name2.erase(i, 1);
name2.insert(i, c);
```

Easier and more efficient would be to just directly `tolower()` the character at the `i`th position:

```
name[i] = std::tolower(name[i]);
```

That being said, simpler would be to lowercase the whole string in one go, and take for granted that some characters will be lowercased unnecessarily:

```
std::transform(name.begin(), name.end(), name.begin(), 
                [](unsigned char c){ return std::tolower(c); }
              );
```

See also: [std::tolower](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower).

Comment: Here is my code

for(int i=0;i<len;++i){

    name[i] =tolower(name[i]);

}

Input and output are  still the same.
What am I doing wrong now?

Comment: Are you sure `len` is correct? What if you replace that with `name.size()`?

Comment: still same, len was basically  name2.length()

Comment: It is hard to say what the problem is without seeing all of the code.

Comment: Nice, too, is a range-based for loop: `for(auto& c : name) { c = tolower(static_cast<unsigned char>(c)); }`

Answer (score 0):

It can be done simply using the range-based for loop.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    std::string s;

    std::cout << "Enter a word: ";
    std::cin >> s;

    for ( char &c : s )
    {
        if ( std::isupper( ( unsigned char )c ) )
        {
            c = tolower( c );
        }
    }

    std::cout << s << '\n';
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Enter a word: Sushant
sushant
```

As for your if statement then at least this sub-statement

```
string tem=to_string(tolower(name2.at(i)));
```

does not make sense. For example

```
std::cout << std::to_string( 'A' ) << '\n';
```

can output

```
65
```

that corresponds to the ASCII value of the character 'A'.

That is the function `std::to_string` converts the promoted code of the character 'A' as an integer to a string.