# Canonicalizing the case of a word entered by the user

Tags: c++, string, c++17

I am building a console bot. There is a way to specify the gender of the user there. Now if the user gives the command `!setgender` then the gender of the user will be asked by the bot. My question is the user can enter male, Male, `mAle`, `maLe`, `malE` ,`mALE` or any form of "male" the user wants (same goes for female and other gender). How can I get any form of "male" (or female, or other) and set the gender to Male (or female or other)?

Comment: @Botje No it does not.

Comment: Why not? Once you case-fold the input to all-lowercase `"male"` you can compare against it.

Comment: I want to show the gender to `Male` @Botje

Comment: What is stopping you? `/* use linked answer to make data lowercase */ if (data == "male") data = "Male";` Done. StackOverflow is not a code writing service, you're still supposed to think for yourself.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about that. Currently i am implementing it. Let's see it works or not, I will notify you in 10 mins 

Comment: Yeah it worked! I implemented the first answer of this question! Thanks for your help too 

Comment: FahimFuad: So, you chose to go with lower-casing the string like @Botje suggested. In that case - this question is a dupe as suggested earlier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transform the input to all lowercase, then the only valid input is `"male"` (shamelessly copied and adopted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/313990/4117728)):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


std::string data;
std::cin >> data;
std::transform(data.begin(), data.end(), data.begin(),
    [](unsigned char c){ return std::tolower(c); });
if (data == "male") {
    data = "M41e"; // whatever you like to have as the "correct" spelling
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I didn't knew about the `std::transform` now I will learn about that! Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @FahumFuad `std::transform` is not the crucial part, `std::tolower` is

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I will learn both! 

Answer (score 0):

[Reference](https://thispointer.com/c-case-insensitive-string-comparison-using-stl-c11-boost-library/)

```
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
bool caseInSensStringCompare(const std::string &str1, const std::string str2)
{
    return ((str1.size() == str2.size()) &&
            std::equal(str1.begin(), str1.end(), str2.begin(), [](char c1, char c2) {
                return (c1 == c2 || std::toupper(c1) == std::toupper(c2));
            }));
}

int main()
{
    std::string gender;
    std::cin >> gender;
    if (caseInSensStringCompare(gender, "male"))
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: While it works, that function should probably take its arguments as const reference, and the lambda should just take chars instead of references to chars.

Comment: @Botje - Thanks to your tips, updated the answer :)