# C++ replace function

Tags: c++, string, char

I am trying to use the replace function to replace uppercase letters with lowercase ones. The way I was trying to do it was that when the letter being checked is between ASCII values 65-90, it would be replaced with the character that is 32 ASCII values higher, for example, 65 would be turned to 97 (A to a).

```
char holder = (userPhrase[count]) + 32;
jumbledPhrase.replace(count, 1, holder);
```

The point of the variable holder
to hold the new value to be used in replace, I am getting an error saying holder does not count as a char parameter in the replace function. Can replace even be used in the way I am trying to use it?

Comment: Unrelated: Is the `tolower` function forbidden for this assignment? Using the library functions is  almost always better because the writers have taken into account many edgecases you may have missed, such as a non-ASCII target, and their assumptions will have held true for millions upon millions of C++ programs.

Comment: If you get a compiler error please post the error in the question and show a [mre].
Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313970/how-to-convert-stdstring-to-lower-case

Comment: @user4581301 I'm sure it's deliberately ironic that `std::tolower` is completely inappropriate for any multi- or variable-byte length encoding (e.g. UTF-8) and is really only useful for the ancient 8-bit "extended ASCII" codepages. Unless you have tight, controlled input constraints, you should not be writing `std::tolower` in _one_ C++ program, let alone millions upon millions.

Comment: There is the [locale-aware version](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/tolower), but this is more a general problem with C++'s confused handling of wide characters. My point is `tolower` has been deployed countless times over decades with a far higher success rate than the nigh-infinite number of roll-your-own versions out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for

```
jumbledPhrase.replace(count, 1, 1, holder);
```

which is replace `1` (the first 1) character at position `count` in string `jumbledPhrase` with `1` copy (the second 1) of the character `holder`.

Reference [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace), if actually you were looking for something else

Comment: Of course the more straightforward way to do this is `jumbledPhrase[count] = holder;`

Answer (score 6):

Use [`tolower()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/tolower/) and make your (but also your code readers) life easier, by avoiding using magic numbers.

Read other alternatives in [How to convert std::string to lower case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313970/how-to-convert-stdstring-to-lower-case), as @churill commented, such as [`std::transform`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/transform/).

Comment: Related: [What is a magic number, and why is it bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad)

Comment: Good point. I will use that instead. Thanks. I will also look into transform to see how that works. For now john below gave a solution that is working.

Comment: @The_Redhawk glad I helped. All three answers work, just make sure you choose the right one for your needs, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Using `replace()` to replace a single `char` is overkill, just use `operator[]` instead, which you are already using to access the source `char` that is being replaced:

```cpp
char holder = userPhrase[count] + 32;
jumbledPhrase[count] = holder;
```