# Alphabetically sorting the text file with mixed case in c++

Tags: c++

I was trying to sort a file of 1000 unsorted mixed case words into alphabetical order.

Example:
Ancient absent Bow bar Cow cat ...

Give the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;
void bubbleSort(string[],int);
int main() {
    const int size = 1000;
    string words[size];
    ifstream input;
    int index;
    input.open("List of 1000 Mixed Case Words.txt");
    if (input.fail())
    {
        cout << "Error opening file." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            getline(input, words[i]);
        }
    }
    bubbleSort(words, size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << words[i] << endl;
    }

    cout << "Enter the index: ";
    cin >> index;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "The word on that index is " << words[index] << endl;
}
void bubbleSort(string arr[],int size) {
    int maxEle;
    int index;
    for ( maxEle = size -1; maxEle > 0; maxEle--)
    {
        for ( index = 0; index < maxEle; index++)
        {
            if (arr[index] > arr[index +1])
            {
                swap(arr[index], arr[index + 1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result is :
Abraham Lincoln
Actinium
Afghanistan
Barbados
Barium
Belarus
Belgium
...
Zimbabwe
Zinc
Zirconium
absence
abundance
ban
banana
band
...
vaccine
woman
writer
zebra

I'm just starting C++ and this problem is too hard for me right now.
How I can sort the file like the example?

Comment: yeah, but what's the question?

Comment: `if (arr[index] > arr[index +1])` is comparing strings lexicographically. You need to convert what that compares to a unified case (upper or lower) if you want `absence` to come before `Barbados`, etc. You can do it here and heat a dining hall with the wasted CPU, or do it once during the read-in and heat small utility room. It is, after all, still bubblesort, so efficiency is already thrown out the window.

Comment: Expanding on WhozCraig's answer: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313970/how-to-convert-stdstring-to-lower-case for a discussion how to convert a string to lower case.

Comment: some more explanation : the ASCII value of 'a' (97) is higher than of 'A' (65) that explains what you see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if only first letter is uppercase, you can use this function:

```
bool gt(string a, string b){
    if(a[0] < 97)
        a[0] += 32;
    if(b[0] < 97)
        b[0] += 32;

    return a>b;
}
```

then. instead of this

```
if (arr[index] > arr[index +1])
```

you put this

```
if (gt(arr[index] , arr[index +1]))
```

and this should work for you.
Otherwise, just convert the entire word to lower or uppercase.

Comment: Can you explain how `bool gt()` function work?

Comment: ASCII code for 'a' is 97, and ASCII for 'A' is 65. All uppercase letters are below 'a' (97). So, assuming my input consists only of ASCII characters (specifically english letters), if a character ASCII code is below 97 you can assume it is uppercase. In function gt I just converted first letter to lowercase by adding 32. (97 - 65 = 32), and then compared the two strings