# Convert normal iterator of characters to string

Tags: c++, c++11

I am wondering how to convert iterator of characters `__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >` to string in C++?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using std::string;

#define TO_UPPER(s) (transform((s).begin(), (s).end(), (s).begin(), ::toupper))
#define TO_LOWER(s) (transform((s).begin(), (s).end(), (s).begin(), ::tolower))


int main() {
    string str = "Hello world!";

    string result = TO_LOWER(str);

    std::cout << result << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/main.cpp.o
FAILED: CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/main.cpp.o 
/usr/bin/c++   -g -std=gnu++11 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/main.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/main.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/main.cpp.o -c /home/amir-pc/CLionProjects/untitled/main.cpp
/home/amir-pc/CLionProjects/untitled/main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
/home/amir-pc/CLionProjects/untitled/main.cpp:7:31: error: conversion from ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >’ to non-scalar type ‘std::string’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’} requested
    7 | #define TO_LOWER(s) (transform((s).begin(), (s).end(), (s).begin(), ::tolower))
      |                     ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/amir-pc/CLionProjects/untitled/main.cpp:13:21: note: in expansion of macro ‘TO_LOWER’
   13 |     string result = TO_LOWER(str);
      |                     ^~~~~~~~
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Comment: You are successfully doing the conversion, however `std::transform` does not return a `std::string`.  The transformation is done in-place.

Comment: This should be a function, not a macro.

Comment: The error occurs because `std::transform` returns the "past-the-end-of-inserted-values" iterator. `std::string` doesn't support initialization from a single iterator (let alone an output iterator), and even if it did, it would be trying to initialize from the data *after* the data you inserted.

Answer (score 6):

`std::transform` modifies the container in place. You don't need its return value, you can just read the original container.

Also avoid using macros if possible. Prefer functions.

Also note that `std::toupper` causes undefined behavior if given a negative character code. You need to cast the parameter to `unsigned char` first to avoid this.

Here's a good implementation from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper):

> ```
> std::string str_toupper(std::string s) {
>     std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), 
>                 // static_cast<int(*)(int)>(std::toupper)         // wrong
>                 // [](int c){ return std::toupper(c); }           // wrong
>                 // [](char c){ return std::toupper(c); }          // wrong
>                    [](unsigned char c){ return std::toupper(c); } // correct
>                   );
>     return s;
> }
> ```

Comment: Names beginning with `str` are reserved for the C library (and I believe that restriction applies in C++ as well).

Comment: @JerryCoffin Interesting, can you show where the standard says that?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Rereading it, your name is actually all right. It's `str` followed by a lower case letter that's reserved, but followed by an underscore is all right (but it's §7.26.11, in the C standard, in case you still care).

Answer (score 0):

These macros change the string in place

```
#define TO_UPPER(s) (transform((s).begin(), (s).end(), (s).begin(), ::toupper))
#define TO_LOWER(s) (transform((s).begin(), (s).end(), (s).begin(), ::tolower))
```

So just write

```
TO_LOWER(str);
std::cout << str << std::endl;
```

Otherwise write

```
#include <iterator>

//...

string str = "Hello world!";

string result;
result.reserve( str.size() );

std::transform( str.begin(), str.end(), std::back_inserter( result ), ::tolower );

std::cout << result << std::endl;
```

Pay attention to that it is a bad idea to use such macros. At least you could declare inline functions.

Comment: How to not change the string in place and return updated string?

Comment: @Node.JS: Simplest approach would be to do `string result = str;`, then `TO_LOWER(result);`. You've already got the tools written, why complicate things?

Comment: In any event, we've already got [a question for this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/313970/364696) (the answers provide both in place and not-in-place solutions).